# preposition for 'point of investigation'

Tags: academic-writing

We have sampling points where we take water samples from a river. We define them as points of investigation (e.g abb. P1) and use always 'concentrations in the P1' as the point is located in the river. But this sounds somehow strange to me. Is that the proper preposition in such situation?

Answer (score 1):

It would sound more natural to say 'concentrations **at** P1'—conditions are generally present at a point, not in it, and with P1 as a specific label, you can then omit the 'a.'